# Match repeating patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string which consists of repetitions of the following pattern

```
/{\s*%\s*assign\s*\w+\s*=\s*((("|').*("|'))|\d+)\s*%\s*}/
```

The repetitions of the above pattern can be separated by spaces (zero or more) and newline characters (zero or more)

Is there a regex that can return an array of all of the above repetitions?

I believe that due to the `.*` I have included in my pattern this makes things impossible?

In case my pattern is hard to read, I'm basically trying to parse a string that could have the following value :

```
    {% assign some_Variable_Name1 = "http://www.some/value.come" %}
{% assign some_Variable_Name_2 = "http://www.some/value.com.jpg" %} {% assign some_Variable_Name_5 = "http://www.some/value.com.jpg" %}
{% assign some_Variable_Name_3 = 1234 %}


{% assign some_Variable_Name_7 = "http://www.s'ome'/value.com.jpg" %}
```

Based on the above example I would like to get the following array :

```
['{% assign some_Variable_Name1 = "http://www.some/value.come" %}',
 '{% assign some_Variable_Name_2 = "http://www.some/value.com.jpg" %}',     
 '{% assign some_Variable_Name_5 = "http://www.some/value.com.jpg" %}',
 '{% assign some_Variable_Name_3 = 1234 %}',
 '{% assign some_Variable_Name_7 = "http://www.s'ome'/value.com.jpg" %}']
```

Comment: Your edit to the question (which completely changes the scope of the question) doesn't even make sense, the input string and output array don't even match. Roll back to your first revision or post a new question. Your current one is unanswerable.

Comment: My latest edit makes absolute sense. The only thing that has now changed compared to my OP is the value of the strings and the space/newline chars between them. My question is clearly stated on line 6 & the subsequent examples and this has been the case since the OP. You did a great job answering 80% of my question. That doesn't mean that the question has been answered. The fact that the title of the OP might be slightly different from my question on line 6 is a technicality that does not require a new question to be asked or the current answer to be considered as the correct one I'm afraid.

Comment: Don't edit your question so drastically as it invalidates the existing answers. If you have a follow up question post a **new** one. I've left this one as it is now as the second answer came *after* your last major edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is basically ok, you need only to use lazy quantifier `.*?`, instead of greedy quantifier `.*`. `.*` match as much as it can, when `.*?` will match as much as it is necessary for whole regex to match, but not more. So when you change your regex to:

```
{\s*%\s*assign\s*\w+\s*=\s*((("|').*?("|'))|\d+)\s*%\s*}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jF2fR9/2)

it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for that m.cekiera. Your regex actually returns only the values of the assignments and not the whole assignment-string as shown in my example but that's fine. Since you are able to extract all 5 values correctly it means that this regex actually works for all cases my pattern covers so we're on the right path! I now have something to work with. Thanks.

Comment: If you use it with `match()` it would give you expected result in array, [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t1fvamf3/). Is it not what you exatly wanted? You want to get String in form of array?

Comment: Ah yes it's working fine with match. Thank you for your answer m.cekiera and thanks for keeping it professional ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.match` with the greedy `g` modifier to return all matched strings. Throw a catching parentheses group around the whole thing you want to catch and make all other groups non-catching `?:`

```
myString.match(/({\s*%\s*assign\s*\w+\s*=\s*(?:["'].*["']|\d+)\s*%\s*})/g);
```

https://regex101.com/r/jF2fR9/1

Comment: Could you maybe provide me with the pattern you are describing as I've neevr used `greedy g` or `non catching ?:` ?

Comment: @SproutCoder just noticed another group you could get rid of. Answer edited.

Comment: If you use the `test string` I've included at the end of my OP you'll notice that your regex breaks in that case. The 2nd match includes the 3rd but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @SproutCoder It breaks just as much as your original regex does. The question wasn't about fixing the regex though, it was about how to catch patterns. I just also cleaned up the syntax a little (without changing the returned result). If you're having problems with the syntax of your regex, you should post a new question, not edit your old one.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clear in the title of my OP. The question was about fixing my regex in order to catch the pattern mentioned.

Comment: No, it's an entirely new question and you should post it as a new question.